# PSCmdlet calling other command freezes due to long processing time?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I have a `PSCmdlet` written in C# and .NET 3.5 that calls a few other commands that are defined within the same `Cmdlet`.

One of these commands kicks off a full crawl on my SharePoint site and waits for it to complete. Optimistically, these take 5-10 minutes to complete.

Since this command takes so long and the `PowerShell` class runs them synchronously, the console will freeze up in the meantime.

That's fine, but after a few minutes, Windows will assume that it's crashed and bomb out the `PowerShell` console.  How can I keep this from happening?

Here's how I'm running the command:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.Commands.AddCommand("Start-CrawlAndRunSearchCatalog").AddParameter("configFilePath", this.configFilePath);

foreach (string str in ps.AddCommand("Out-String").Invoke<string>())
            this.WriteObject(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
var thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
    ps.Commands.AddCommand("Start-CrawlAndRunSearchCatalog").AddParameter("configFilePath", this.configFilePath);

    foreach (string str in ps.AddCommand("Out-String").Invoke<string>())
        this.WriteObject(str);
});

thread.Start();
thread.Join();
```